# Put request using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to update data on server by using PUT method but I am getting this error , I haven't used volley before ,Is there anything I am missing ?  please suggest .

My code :

```
private void sendRequest() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        PersonalInfoModel.Data.PersonalInformation.Address  address;
        address = new  PersonalInfoModel().new Data().new PersonalInformation().new Address();
        address.setBuilding("test");
        address.setCountry("test");
        address.setCounty("test");
        address.setPostcodeInCode("");
        address.setPostcodeOutCode("");
        address.setTown("");

        PersonalInfoModel.Data.PersonalInformation  data;
        data = new  PersonalInfoModel().new Data().new PersonalInformation();
        data.setDob("tsst");
        data.setEmail("testemai");
        data.setForename("test");
        data.setSurname("data");
        data.setAddress(address);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JSONString = gson.toJson(data);
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(JSONString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "JSONString  is :: " + JSONString.toString());
        JsonObjectRequest putRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, urlUserDetail, obj,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // response
                        LogUtils.LOGD("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        LogUtils.LOGD("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        ) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tess", "2222");
                params.put("Authorization", "def1bc98d032");
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {

                try {
                    LogUtils.LOGD("json", obj.toString());
                    return obj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        queue.add(putRequest);


    }
```

Error :

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for url
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tess", "2222");
                params.put("Authorization", "def1bc98d032");

              // add this parameter
               params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return params;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Check with PostMan or some client and check if you are getting a right response back and eliminate that possibility - the request works without using android volley
2. Response code 400 means Bad request. It means that the request you're making is incorrect. Possibly the content type has an error, try adding

   `params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` to `getHeaders()`

Answer (score 1):

try removing the getbody method.. because you are sending the request parameters as a json object and content type header is also application/json.so getbody won't be necessary

Answer (score 0):

`JsonObjectRequest` adds `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` by default. Your `params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` adds another `Content-Type` and some applications don't work with multiple `Content-Type` definitions. You should try to remove `params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the request URL for a PUT request has the id of the resource as the last path segment. Otherwise you will get a 404.

```
Wrong form of URL:

/users

Correct form of URL:

/users/bob
```